# Read string with caret symbol from windows console

Tags: windows, console, cmd, caret

I'm working on my own parser for mathematical functions as `sin(x^2)` in ANSI C. I've done really good code, but I need to read expression from console (cmd) and in `argv[1]`, where should be whole expression is expression like `x2` instead of `x^2`. Is there a way, how to compel console to read whole string with caret `^` symbol as a parameter?
I've tried to search something on google and here, but nothing useful.

Comment: The ^ character means something to the command processor.  It is the *escape character*, similar to how `\\` is the escape in C code.  You'll need to use double quotes around the argument.  Or make it interactive by prompting the user for the expression in your program.

Comment: It's common to use `**` rather tha `^` to express power. Since `^` is indeed a special symbol to `cmd`, perhaps `^^` woud work, but it would be just as much a pain to process within your batch.

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh, I forgot to try this. Thank you!