# Using composer require without quotes

Tags: windows, cmd, composer-php

Why does

```
composer require symfony/symfony ~4.4
```

install Symfony 4.4.43 (as of 6 July 2022), and

```
composer require symfony/symfony ^4.4
```

installs Symfony 4.4.0 (not what I asked for), and

```
composer require symfony/symfony 4.4
```

installs Symfony 4.4.0 (sensible default), but

```
composer require symfony/symfony "^4.4"
```

installs the latest version of Symfony 4.4.43 (as it should)?

My platform is Windows 10, using the command prompt.

Why are the double quotes needed for Composer to recognise the `^` character?

Comment: The `^` character means something to the command processor. It is the escape character, similar to how `\\` is the escape in C code. You'll need to use double quotes around the argument. Or use the interactive prompt of the Composer program. Compare _[Read string with caret symbol from windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20874104/367456)_ and _[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)_.

Comment: @hakre Can you use Composer's interactive mode after setting up the project? I thought it was once only?

Comment: Good question. Could be my suggestion is only limited to first use. Have to try otherwise (and did so): Yes, good news, you can. Caveat: just run `composer require` (without specifying the package name) on an interactive shell and you'll be asked (My Composer version 2.2.14 2022-06-06 16:32:50). That should prevent the encoding/escaping problem. Otherwise I think `^^`  (doubling the caret symbol) can do it when entering the command (or adding quotes but I have to Windows cmd here to actually try before suggesting, better check the last link on the ss64.com site for details).

Comment: @hakre I did try `^^` before posting the question but it was also stripped off.

Comment: Well, I don't have `cmd` at hand (and none with Composer) so that what just from memory. In my answer I suggest quotes (double quotes) which should hopefully do it. Please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I should have tried `^^^^`, the way if you want a single backslash in PHP you often have to type `'\\\\'`!

Comment: OK, so it doesn't matter how many `^` characters you have outside of double quotes, they all get stripped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are the double quotes needed for Composer to recognise the `^` character?

Because the `^` has special meaning on the command prompt, it (the caret "`^`") is the [*escape character <sup>WP</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) on the Windows command prompt, mind:

> My platform is Windows 10, using the command prompt.

**Unfortunately** the caret `^` has as well special meaning for the version constraint (compare [*Caret Version Range <sup>Composer</sup>*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-) as well as for NPM/YARN etc.) so the character needs to be escape as well.

One way to do this is to quote the value to remove the special meaning on the commandline and then it works as you have tried yourself already:

```
composer require symfony/symfony "^4.4"
```

So the shorter answer on windows is: Quote the version constrain in double quotes with `composer require` so that a potential caret `^` gets passed to the Composer command verbatim: `"^4.4"`.

Btw. something similar is the case on a Linux command prompt, the tilde `~` character can have special meaning (path to the `USER`s `HOME` directory) when at the beginning of a command line argument. Here again quoting in double quotes prevents having the special meaning: `"~4.4.0"` (compare [*Tilde Version Range <sup>Composer</sup>*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-)).