# Install mpdf v8.0.4 for php 7.4 Version

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, mpdf, laravel-dompdf

I am running on PHP v 7.4 after an upgrade from the 7.1 version
I am having issues on install mpdf v8.0.4 since its compatible with php 7.4 version

The error facing after ruuning composer update

```
 mpdf/mpdf[v7.0.0-beta1, ..., v7.0.0-beta2] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 -> your php version (7.4.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

running these two commands turns unsuccessfully

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf v8.0.4
composer require mpdf/mpdf dev-php7-support
```

Comment: how about updating your `composer.json` manually and then running `composer update` ?

Comment: what to update in the composer.json file?

Comment: You should have `"mpdf/mpdf": "^7"` or something in there right now you can change the `^7` to `^8`

Comment: when i tried to run this command: "composer require mpdf/mpdf: ^8  i got an error - Invalid arguments - Could not find  package 8

Comment: Try modifying your composer.json file

Comment: like what exactly to change and update

Comment: Open your `composer.json` file. Search for the line that says `"mpdf/mpdf": "^7"` or something like that and change the "^7..." part to "^8"

Comment: Regarding the error message _"Invalid arguments - Could not find package 8"_: You're running the composer command on a Windows command prompt. `^`  is an **escape character**, a meta-character, there (compare Q&A [_Using composer require without quotes_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72877159/367456) for more info and alternatives, check the comments there): `composer require "mpdf/mpdf" "^8"` (or leave the version constraint out: `composer require "mpdf/mpdf"` and composer should find the fitting version).